# storing user input in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I need to do the following (I'm a beginner in programming so please excuse me for my ignorance): I have to ask the user for three different pieces of information on three different text boxes on a form. Then the user has a button called "enter"and when he clicks on it the texts he entered on the three fields should be stored on three different arrays, at this stage I also want to see the user's input to check data is actually being stored in the array. I have beem trying unsuccessfully to get the application to store or show the data on just one of the arrays. I have 2 files: film.html and functions.js. Here's the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Film info</title>

    <script src="jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
        <body>

        <div id="form">

            <h1><b>Please enter data</b></h1>
        <hr size="3"/>
        <br>

            <label for="title">Title</label> <input id="title" type="text" > 
        <br>

            <label for="name">Actor</label><input id="name" type="text">
        <br>

            <label for="tickets">tickets</label><input id="tickets" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>

            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert(this.form.title.value)">
            <input type="button" value="Show data" onclick="show()"> <br>

            <h2><b>Data:</b></h2>
        <hr>
        </div>

        <div id= "display">

        </div>
        </body>

</html>

var title=new Array();
var name=new Array();
var tickets=new Array();

function insert(val){
  title[title.length]=val;
  }

function show() {
  var string="<b>All Elements of the Array :</b><br>";
  for(i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
  string =string+title[i]+"<br>";
  }
  if(title.length > 0)
 document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = string;
  }
```

Answer (score 19):

You're not actually going out after the values. You would need to gather them like this:

```
var title   = document.getElementById("title").value;
var name    = document.getElementById("name").value;
var tickets = document.getElementById("tickets").value;
```

You could put all of these in one array:

```
var myArray = [ title, name, tickets ];
```

Or many arrays:

```
var titleArr   = [ title ];
var nameArr    = [ name ];
var ticketsArr = [ tickets ];
```

Or, if the arrays already exist, you can use their `.push()` method to push new values onto it:

```
var titleArr = [];

function addTitle ( title ) {
  titleArr.push( title );
  console.log( "Titles: " + titleArr.join(", ") );
}
```

Your save button doesn't work because you refer to `this.form`, however you don't have a form on the page. In order for this to work you would need to have `<form>` tags wrapping your fields:

I've made several corrections, and placed the changes on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ufanep/2/edit

The new form follows:

```
<form>
  <h1>Please enter data</h1>
  <input id="title" type="text" />
  <input id="name" type="text" />
  <input id="tickets" type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert()" />
  <input type="button" value="Show data" onclick="show()" />
</form>
<div id="display"></div>
```

There is still some room for improvement, such as removing the `onclick` attributes (those bindings should be done via JavaScript, but that's beyond the scope of this question).

I've also made some changes to your JavaScript. I start by creating three empty arrays:

```
var titles  = [];
var names   = [];
var tickets = [];
```

Now that we have these, we'll need references to our input fields.

```
var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
var nameInput   = document.getElementById("name");
var ticketInput = document.getElementById("tickets");
```

I'm also getting a reference to our message display box.

```
var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");
```

The `insert()` function uses the references to each input field to get their value. It then uses the `push()` method on the respective arrays to put the current value into the array.

Once it's done, it cals the `clearAndShow()` function which is responsible for clearing these fields (making them ready for the next round of input), and showing the combined results of the three arrays.

```
function insert ( ) {
 titles.push( titleInput.value );
 names.push( nameInput.value );
 tickets.push( ticketInput.value );

 clearAndShow();
}
```

This function, as previously stated, starts by setting the `.value` property of each input to an empty string. It then clears out the `.innerHTML` of our message box. Lastly, it calls the `join()` method on all of our arrays to convert their values into a comma-separated list of values. This resulting string is then passed into the message box.

```
function clearAndShow () {
  titleInput.value = "";
  nameInput.value = "";
  ticketInput.value = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + titles.join(", ") + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "Names: " + names.join(", ") + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "Tickets: " + tickets.join(", ");
}
```

The final result can be used online at http://jsbin.com/ufanep/2/edit

Comment: Don't forget to .value these to get the value of what was entered in the input field

Comment: Thank you very much! This site's great! I'll study your corrections and keep on working. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You have at least these 3 issues:

1. you are not getting the element's value properly
2. The div that you are trying to use to display whether the values have been saved or not has id `display` yet in your javascript you attempt to get element `myDiv` which is not even defined in your markup.
3. **Never** name variables with reserved keywords in javascript. using "string" as a variable name is NOT a good thing to do on most of the languages I can think of. I renamed your string variable to "content" instead. See below.

You can save all three values at once by doing:

```
var title=new Array();
var names=new Array();//renamed to names -added an S- 
                      //to avoid conflicts with the input named "name"
var tickets=new Array();

function insert(){
    var titleValue = document.getElementById('title').value;
    var actorValue = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var ticketsValue = document.getElementById('tickets').value;
    title[title.length]=titleValue;
    names[names.length]=actorValue;
    tickets[tickets.length]=ticketsValue;
  }
```

And then change the show function to:

```
function show() {
  var content="<b>All Elements of the Arrays :</b><br>";
  for(var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
     content +=title[i]+"<br>";
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
     content +=names[i]+"<br>";
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
     content +=tickets[i]+"<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content; //note that I changed 
                                                    //to 'display' because that's
                                              //what you have in your markup
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsuxV/) for you to play around.

Comment: Thank you very much!I'll take a look and apply your corrections!