# saving user input to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I have an assignment for my course I am battling with. I have to save user input (from answers to 9 math problems) into an array when the "submit" button is clicked and then use the array to perform functions like checking how many answers are correct and showing hit rate. I have written the html with a table and form combination but not sure how to start with the javascript.
Thanks!

Comment: arrays can be instatiated using `[]` ... added to using `.push` ... there's a start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523200/storing-user-input-in-array  this should help you get started

Comment: If you're going to ask here,  may add well share your html thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Give id to all text box like this
I have included one text box, You can include it how much ever u want

```
<input name="text" type="text" maxlength="512" id="answer1" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
function myFunction(){
var array= [];
var value = document.getElementById('answer1').value
array.push(value);
for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    //perform your operations
}}
```