# JS and/or D3 Methods of storing Dynamic User Inputs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My question is similar to the one posed here: [storing user input in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523200/storing-user-input-in-array)

My use case is different in one crucial aspect, **I do not have static inputs**. At any one time, there could be anywhere from 1 to 3 user number inputs on my page. They are also removed dynamically too, so I can't just create them all, then style them as needed something like using `display:hidden;`.

**My question is:** What is a js solution that can store user inputs into an array robust to inputs that may or may not have been appended without an if clause for each array in the event the element hasn't been appended yet(`!==null`).

**Or** if d3 has a simpler approach than native javascript to store number inputs into an array, that would be an acceptable answer too. I postulated this selection: `d3.selectAll('#input1,#input2,#input3')` but I'm not sure if values can be retrieved and stored in an array from such a selection.

Here is a worked-out example:

The document could potentially have 3 inputs, but lets say the **current** state of the document only has 2 inputs with IDs: `#input1` and `#input2`. So I need to store the values of the existing inputs, and a 0 for `#input3` because it has not been created yet. I'm not sure how to create an array comprehension with these requirements. I was thinking something like:

```
my_array.push(d3.selectAll('#input1,#input2,#input3').each().value())
```

But like I said above, I want the array to contain the value for each input. `push()` would just add another item to the array. The array would exceed 3 values if the event listener was triggered more than 3 times, which is not what I want. I just want an array that is updated with the current values of all existing number inputs (and a value of 0 if input has not been appended yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but it seems to me that you want to get all the values of the inputs, without knowing how many of them you have on the page.

If that's the case, you can simply use...

```
d3.selectAll("input[type=number]")
```

..., which will get all the inputs present on the page when you call the function.

Here is a demo, look at the console:

```js
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var inputs = [];
  d3.selectAll("input[type=number]").each(function() {
    inputs.push(this.value);
  })
  console.log(inputs);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <h1><b>Please enter data</b></h1>
  <hr size="3" />
  <br>
  <label for="input 1">Input 1</label>
  <input id="input1" type="number">
  <br>
  <label for="input 2">Input 2</label>
  <input id="input2" type="number">
  <br>
  <label for="input 3">Input 3</label>
  <input id="input3" type="text">
  <br>
  <hr>
</div>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: I just revised the post for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I just saw it, thanks. As I suspected, you simply want to get all inputs present on the page, without previously knowing how many. So, you can test my solution.

Comment: I have other inputs that are not of type number. So I think that would interfere with the selection. Is there something like: `d3.selectAll('input[type=number]')` Or do I have to assign a specific class to narrow down the selection?

Comment: The other thing I tried to clarify in my post is if I use `push()` then the array could exceed the total number of inputs, as the number of calls goes past 4. Is there a way to just **update** the `inputs` array to contain the current values of the inputs (which in my case is at most 3)?

Comment: If you look at my snippet, you're gonna see that the array is empty every time you push the button. I believe the best idea is posting another question, since this is actually another issue.