# How to take user input and add to array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I've got a page im trying to develop which will take user input and then add it to an array and then take that array and make a select and option list out of it as such.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 var option_list = [];
   // for loop at thats option_list to select select tag
 for (var i = 0; i < option_list.length; i++){
  var opt = option_list[i];
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  var select = document.getElementById("select");     
  option.setAttribute("id", opt); //Adding ID to the option list
  option.setAttribute("class", "intersect-option"); // adds classes to option
  option.value(opt); // adds value to option list 
  select.appendChild(option); // Adds option to the list.

} 
function add_option(name){
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
name.push(option_list());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="name" value="">
 <input type="button" onclick="add_option()" value="add person">
 <select id="select">
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue i am having is that it says when i try and input the information i get back-

> Uncaught TypeError: option_list is not a function
>
> at add_option (selectTest.html:19)
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (selectTest.html:25)

I am unsure what i am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to call `option_list` as a function in the last line of your script (`name.push(option_list());`). The correct syntax would be `option_list.push(name)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing user input in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523200/storing-user-input-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push `name` into option_list array. The correct syntax is `option_list.push(name);`

```
function add_option(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    option_list.push(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pushing elements into array works the other way:

```
option_list.push(name);
```

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

```
name.push(option_list());
```

As it says, option_list is not a function, and balanced parentheses after an identifier designate a function call in C family languages, so option_list() is not a valid expression.

Additionally, did you really intend to loop from zero up to the length of an empty array (which is equally zero)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="text" id="name" value="">
     <input type="button" onclick="add_option()" value="add person">
     <select id="select">
    </select>
    <script>
     var option_list = [];
       // for loop at thats option_list to select select tag

     
      var select = document.getElementById("select");     

    function add_option(name){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
     var option = document.createElement("option");
      var label = document.createTextNode(name);
      option.setAttribute("id", name); //Adding ID to the option list
      option.setAttribute("class", "intersect-option"); // adds classes to option
      option.value = name; // adds value to option list 
      
      option.appendChild(label);
      select.appendChild(option); // Adds option to the list.
    }



    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you find it useful.Please tick it as answer.