# How to create a function in typescript which takes array as an user input and how to find array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, types

I need to create a function in typescript that takes array as an input that accept any type of array. and then calculate the number of elements present in it and return it.

I want a output like
let  if user input : ["cricket","football"]
then output : 2

how to solve this this using typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storing user input in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523200/storing-user-input-in-array)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the generic type T to allow any type of array in parameter

```
arrayLength<T>(myArray:T[]): number {
    return myArray.length;
}
```

Comment: great if it help you. may i ask you to mark the reply to close the topic if it solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is like so:

```
// We tell ts to expect an array of any type as parameter and return a number
function arrLength(someArray : any[]) : number {
    return someArray.length;
}

// Test array with a length of 6
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3];

// Should output 6
console.log(arrLength(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check this tutorial out on how to pass an array to a function:>> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

To calculate the length of an array, it'll be like this:

```
console.log(array.length);
```

Detailed documentation:>> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length